# Check foreign table owner on Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a foreign table on Postgres, linking to another server. I'm trying to select on this table, but I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation whitelist
```

Anyone knows how to check the ownership of a foreign table?
I've tried this, but it returns info just about local tables...

```
select t.table_name, t.table_type, c.relname, c.relowner, u.usename
from information_schema.tables t
join pg_catalog.pg_class c on (t.table_name = c.relname)
join pg_catalog.pg_user u on (c.relowner = u.usesysid)
where t.table_schema='schema_name';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any admin tool should be able to tell you who owns a foreign table (or any other database object, for that matter). In pgAdmin, the owner appears in the Properties tab when you select the foreign table in the object browser, and psql will report the owner when you run `\dE`.

If you really need a query, this should do it:

```
SELECT
  oid::regclass,
  pg_get_userbyid(relowner)
FROM pg_class
WHERE relkind = 'f'
```